# Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_result::$level

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, controller

I have a difficulty on my program. The error say :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_result::$level
>
> Filename: controllers/Auth.php
>
> Line Number: 30
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PKLTelkom\Telkom2\application\controllers\Auth.php
>   Line: 30 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\PKLTelkom\Telkom2\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Here's my controller named "Auth" :

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/
class Auth extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_login');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view("login");
    }

    public function AksiLogin()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $passwordx = md5($password);
        $login = $this->m_login->data_login($username, $passwordx);
        $tes = count($login);
        if ($tes > 0) {
            //ambil detail data
            $row = $this->m_login->data_login($username, $passwordx);
            $level = $row->level;
            //daftarkan session
            $data_session = array('level' => $level);
            $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
            //direct page
            if ($level == 'superadmin') {
                redirect('superadmin');
            }
            else if ($level == 'admin') {
                redirect('admin');
            }

        }
        else {
            $this->index();
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata("login");
        $this->session->unset_userdata("username");
        redirect ('index.php/auth');
    }
    }
?>
```

Here's my models named "M_Login" :

```
<?php
class M_login extends CI_Model
{

function data_login($username, $password)
{
 $this->db->where('username', $username);
 $this->db->where('password', $password);
 return $this->db->get('akun');
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Line 30 `$level = $row->level;`. You're not returning `level` in your query.

Comment: @ourmandave where should I return the `level`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `return $this->db->get('akun');` on "M_login" model doesn't return object with the name `level`.

Try changing this line on "M_Login" model :

```
<?php
class M_login extends CI_Model
{

function data_login($username, $password)
{
$this->db->where('username', $username);
$this->db->where('password', $password);
return $this->db->get('akun')->row(); // change this line
}
}
?>
```